# Dashboard from Firestore data?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, dashboard, firebase-analytics

I have made a simple Android app with Flutter, that sends data to Firestore. Now, I need to build a dashboard that will be able to view the data. Excel doesn't work, I tried Zapier but it seems too limited, and I gave a look at Retool , but it seems to only work with RealTime database, not Firestore yet.

Would you guys be able to recommend something ?

Answer (score 2):

Zapier does the job. I just had to name every row accordingly to the fields from firestore

Answer (score 0):

[Chartbrew.com](https://chartbrew.com/product/firebase-charts-dashboard) supports connections to Firestore. You can run queries using Firestore operations and generate charts and tables to explore the data.